# Using grep command in linux on specific strings

Tags: linux, grep

Lets consider a list containing next lines:

```
site.com/link1/index.php
site.org/link1/index.php
site.com/link2/page/index.php
site.ru/link1/index.php
site.no/link3/index.php
site.com/link3/index.php
site.no/link/page/index.php
```

How do I grep and save in a separate file just lines containing specific strings after domain extension (like .ru, .com, .no, .org)
For i.e. I want to save just lines containing link1, org link2 ...
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You can use `-E` option (Regular Expressions). In your case, it would be:

`grep -E "\.\w{2,3}\/link[12]" yourFile.txt > newFile.txt`

Where:

- `-E` means Regular expression;
- `> newFile.txt` will put the result
  of grep in the newFile.txt;

About the regular expression:

- `\.\w{2,3}` means all lines that contains a dot (`\.`) followed by
  2 or 3 word characters (`\w{2,3}`);
- `\/link[12]` a literal slash (`\/`) followed by the text `link` that, in turn, must be followed by number 1 or 2 (`[12]`). You could change `[12]` by `\d+` that means any number with one or more digits.

Hope to help you.

Reference: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/using-grep-regular-expressions-to-search-for-text-patterns-in-linux